# Magento 1.9 appearance differences HTTP vs HTTPS

Tags: magento, http, https

I am at a dead end on how to resolve an appearance issue with a site I am working on, hopefully someone has a fix.  I suspect it is somehow to do with HTTPS.

With the Live site (HTTPS) set to responsive 1280px, the display area is narrower truncating the menu  and altering the appearance of the footer.

However, on the staging site (HTTP) the appearance is different, appearing how I would like it.

Both sites are identical apart from the HTTPS vs HTTP.  I have proven this by creating another staging site from a direct copy of the live site and still have the same bizzare appearance differencesI am at a dead end on how to resolve an appearance issue with a site I am working on, hopefully someone has a fix.  I suspect it is somehow to do with HTTPS.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3grr.jpg
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ6F9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can bring up the network tab in the developer console and check if any resources (such as CSS or JavaScript) aren't being properly loaded over HTTPS. After that you can investigate why they aren't being loaded.